# Implode not showing result php

Tags: php, string

I have an simple code like this :-

```
  $array = array(0 => 47, 1 => 51);
    foreach($array as $key => $gg1){
       $commaList = implode(', ', $gg1);
        echo $commaList;
    }
```

But its not showing the output I want:-

```
 '47', '51'
```

Comment: you dont need to loop if you are using implode

Comment: Hmmm how to do it either way then?

Comment: Open `implode` manual __please__.

Comment: Ok it worked Thanks

Comment: @JeffB if it works for you, you should consider accepting an answer (mark green tick :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to loop, if you are using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array
>   elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.

Simply do the following:

```
// Your input array
$input = array([0] => 47, [1] => 51);

// Simply use implode function to convert an array to 
// a string where array values are separated by a delimiter (',')
$commaList = implode(', ', $input);

echo $commaList; // prints out 47, 51

// Based on OP's comments, add double quotes also
$commaDoubleQuoteList = '"' . implode('", "' , $input) . '"';

echo $commaDoubleQuoteList; // prints out "47", "51"

// Based on OP's edit, add single quotes
// notice the reversal of " with '
$commaSingleQuoteList = "'" . implode("', '" , $input) . "'";

echo $commaSingleQuoteList; // prints out '47', 51'
```

Comment: Is there a way to add double qoutes with comma aslo there to it?

Comment: @JeffB yes we can. Please give what is your expected output! I will edit the answer to add that case as well

Comment: One more fix... He needs space after comma :D

Answer (score 1):

you dont need loop try this

```
$array = array(0 => 47, 1 => 51);
$commaList = implode(', ', $array);
echo $commaList;
```